# How to use loadObjects with ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

This is my **ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter :**

```
 // Set up a customized query
    ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter<PlaceFilters,PhotoFiltersAdapter> mainAdapter = new ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter<>(this, PhotoFiltersAdapter.class
               ,"PlaceFilters");
                public ParseQuery<PlaceFilters> create() {
                    Location myLoc = (currentLocation == null) ? lastLocation : currentLocation;
                    ParseQuery<PlaceFilters> query = PlaceFilters.getQuery();
                    query.include("user");
                    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                    query.whereWithinKilometers("location", geoPointFromLocation(myLoc), radius);
                    query.setLimit(6);
                    return query;
                }
```

This the doListQuery Method in which I want to call loadobjects into RecyclerView when `location!=null`

```
/*
     * Set up a query to update the list view
     */
    private void doListQuery() {
        Location myLoc = (currentLocation == null) ? lastLocation : currentLocation;
        // If location info is available, load the data
        if (myLoc != null) {
            // Refreshes the list view with new data based
            // usually on updated location data.
        }
    }
```

This is the my **ViewHolder Class :**

```
   public class PhotoFiltersAdapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public PhotoFiltersAdapter(View view) {
    super(view);
    PlaceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.place_names);
     }
       @Bind(R.id.place_names)
         @ParseName("PlaceName")
        public TextView PlaceName;
}
```

Then my **ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter Class :**

```
public class FiltersQueryAdapter extends ParseRecyclerQueryAdapter<PlaceFilters, PhotoFiltersAdapter> {



    public FiltersQueryAdapter(Context context, Class clazz,QueryFactory queryFactory) {
        super(context, clazz, queryFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PhotoFiltersAdapter holder, int position) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
        holder.PlaceName.setText(object.getString("PlaceName"));
    }

}
```

This is my **Parse Objects Class :**

```
@ParseClassName("PlaceFilters")
public class PlaceFilters extends ParseObject{

    public String getText() {
        return getString("PlaceName");
    }

    public ParseGeoPoint getLocation() {
        return getParseGeoPoint("GeoArea");
    }

    public static ParseQuery<PlaceFilters> getQuery() {
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(PlaceFilters.class);
    }
}
```